# CGID error on Apache 2.4.10

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

After updating to Apache 2.4.10 on an internal web site, the error log is constantly showing messages like the one below.

[Mon Jan 19 09:04:40.191633 2015] [cgid:error] [pid 4915436:tid 2314] (32)Broken pipe: [client x.x.x.x:60715] AH02550: Failed to flush CGI output to client

This message comes up when the home page is called. The page will load correctly for clients, but the page does not use CGI at all.

For a page that pulls a large amount of data, the page times out after about one minute. I've set the CGIDScriptTimout to 300, but that did not help.

The web pages are Perl programs.

Has anyone else seen this error?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same message appears repeatedly in our logs after recently upgrading Apache from 2.4.9 to 2.4.12, yet everything in our web application continues to work as it did before.

Recent Apache source code contains these lines in modules/generators/mod_cgid.c:

```
rv = ap_pass_brigade(r->output_filters, bb);
if (rv != APR_SUCCESS) { 
        /* APLOG_ERR because the core output filter message is at error,
         * but doesn't know it's passing CGI output 
         */
        ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, rv, r, APLOGNO(02550) "Failed to flush CGI output to client");
    }
```

...whereas in earlier versions it just had:

```
ap_pass_brigade(r->output_filters, bb);
```

So if I'm reading this right, Apache used to ignore the return value of the function in this context, and more recently somebody decided it might be important.

If you feel the message is uselessly cluttering up your logfiles, you might try changing the APLOG_ERR constant to APLOG_INFO or APLOG_DEBUG, and compiling it that way.